# How do I stop playing?

Tags: draw-something

In Draw Something, occasionally I'll see a message that my opponent has resigned from the game. It's nothing to do with the quality of my fat-fingered drawings, I assure you.

But I do wonder - how are they doing this? How do you resign a game? I've not seen any option anywhere. Long-clicking on a game brings up no menu, and there doesn't seem to be an option in the Gears menu, either.

I'm playing on Android, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you swipe left on a game from the main menu, the green "Play" changes to a red "Delete" button. This will allow you to "resign" from a game and remove it from the list.

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I don't remember seeing any explanation of this in the game :/

Comment: @Alex Some of the interstitial advertisements display tips for the game, and one of those is that you can do this to remove games you're no longer interested in playing

Comment: But the ads don't pop up if you've bought the game. At least, I don't remember seeing any since I bought it.