# What to do if the other player's drawing is blank?

Tags: draw-something

I am just playing with a random player but at the second turn I got the notification that his/her drawing is ready, but when I play the video nothing occurs, the drawing is always blank.

What does it mean and what options do I have now?

Comment: Maybe he did so on purpose? What letters do you have? It could be 'WHITE', 'BLANK', 'EMPTY', 'NOTHING' ...

Comment: @badp I thought the same, but the word is 8 characters long. Letters are: H M C I D O V H E R R T

Comment: http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=HMCIDOVHERRT&language=english&t=1000&d=&include=&exclude=&n=8&m=&source=adv&a=n&l=y&q=n&k=1 says it's either DIRECTOR or CREDITOR :P

Comment: @badp HAAACK! I am joking, if have no chance I will try one of the two suggested, thank you. But what I am supposed to do in these cases? Try to guess or just give up?

Comment: @Drake there really isn't a winning or losing condition in Draw Something so giving up would be logical. If they didn't draw anything and sent it back they are boring anyway. Its just a random person anyway.

Comment: @Emerica I have just installed Draw Something and didn't understand how the game works. Probably you are right, giving up is the right way.

Comment: @Drake The game is very broken and becomes boring quickly. Mainly becasue 1.You can just exit the app and get no words so the bombs are worthless and 2.There is no way to end/win/lose. Its not competetive and it has no purpose. It will just go on forever and theres no guessing limit.

Comment: Really I think your problem is with your mindset. You're not _fighting_ a random player, you're **playing** with them. This is co-op, not deathmatch :)

Comment: @Tacroy Yep, you are right, was my second attempt so it wasn't really clear the game target. I am going to change that term in my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw Something has its fair share of bugs so there is a slight chance the empty drawing is a bug, in which case using an anagram finder is the best bet to be able to continue your streak. However given that it's a random person it seems most likely that they're just a troll, in which case you're better off just [deleting that game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/60794/1561) and finding a new drawing partner who will play the game properly. Also, you can use bombs so you have an easier time "figuring it out" and if this person is your friend text them and ask what it was supposed to be.

Comment: I'd recommend http://www.omghalp.com/, which appears to be made specifically for solving Draw Something anagrams