# How to stop playing with a player without being forced to quit and restart?

Tags: draw-something

I don't know what's happening with Draw Something but apparently 30/50% of players prefer not play the game and write directly the word I have to guess.

I don't like it so I prefer to Pass and abandon the game with that player, but it seems not possible to do, at least on Android, after you have passed. The only possibility I found was to exit the game, relaunch it, and perform the action already [described here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60794/how-do-i-stop-playing).

It is a bit annoying considering the high percentage of these players. Do you know any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it seems not possible. The only ways are:

- quit the game and relaunch it

or

- just pass, draw blank (suggested by @xy in comments)

and then quit the match using dedicated gesture as [described here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60794/how-do-i-stop-playing).

Answer (score 5):

You click on the persons name who you want to end the game with then swipe left to right and click on the X .

Answer (score 0):

Well on the menu where you have the name of player you want to stop playing with you simply swipe your finger to the left on that game which will give you a red button stating delete which will delete that game/player from your list of current games

Comment: Hi Momin, welcome to Arqade!  This answer doesn't actually answer the original question, and might get downvoted.  To add more information, use the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

On my iPhone11 I sent a wrong picture to the person and when it goes back to their name there is an x to click on and it gives you the choice to delete them.